# How do different retention policies affect my annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

Can anyone explain in a clear way the practical differences between the `java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy` constants `SOURCE`, `CLASS`, and `RUNTIME`?

I'm also not exactly sure what the phrase "retaining annotation" means.

Comment: The documentation ( http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html ) is very clear.

Comment: yes I already read but I don't understand in practice how it works. In fact if i try 'this phrase':
""""
Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler but need not be retained by the VM at run time. """

and then open a decompiled class where I put an annotation with retention policy CLASS I don't find nothing...

Comment: Then your decompiler doesn't seem to support annotations. jd-gui works fine.

Comment: Thanks the problem was my decompiler dj and jad ... jd-gui show me!!

Answer (score 237, accepted):

> - `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE`: Discard during
>     the compile. These annotations don't
>     make any sense after the compile   has
>     completed, so they aren't written to
>     the bytecode.
>     Example: `@Override`, `@SuppressWarnings`
> - `RetentionPolicy.CLASS`: Discard during
>     class load. Useful when doing
>     bytecode-level post-processing.
>     Somewhat  surprisingly, this is the
>     default.
> - `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`: Do not
>     discard. The annotation should be
>     available for reflection at runtime.
>     Example: `@Deprecated`

**Source:**
The old URL is dead now 
<strike>[hunter_meta](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/hunter_meta_2.html)</strike> and replaced with [hunter-meta-2-098036](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/hunter-meta-2-098036.html). In case even this goes down, I am uploading the image of the page.

**[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krWXe.png) (Right Click and Select 'Open Image in New Tab/Window')**
[image: Screenshot of Oracle website]

Comment: thanks for the quote, the most interesting here is the use case for `RetentionPolicy.CLASS`

Comment: can you explain why RetentionPolicy.class is interesting / surprisingly the default?

Comment: @sudocoder - Refer to these links: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5971247/373861 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3849602/373861. I beleive this particular policy is needed for bytecode instrumentation. Though I never used it myself.

Comment: At the end it says *In the next article in this series, I'll show how Java's reflection capabilities have been enhanced to help you discover annotations at runtime and how the Annotation Processing Tool "apt" lets you use annotations at build-time.*, where is this article?

Comment: @Sushant: Well I am not sure where is it :). Though `apt` is deprecated refer to this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/GettingStarted.html. For discovering annotation using reflection there are multiple tutorials on internet. You can start by looking into `java.lang.Class::getAnno*` and similar methods in `java.lang.reflect.Method` and `java.lang.reflect.Field`.

Comment: I could not find fourth [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/hunter-meta-3-092019.html)

Answer (score 73):

According to your comments about class decompilation, here is how I think it should work:

- `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE`: Won't appear in the decompiled class
- `RetentionPolicy.CLASS`: Appear in the decompiled class, but can't be inspected at run-time with reflection with `getAnnotations()`
- `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`: Appear in the decompiled class, and can be inspected at run-time with reflection with `getAnnotations()`

Comment: Yes too me thinked so but in the decompiled class nothing is present!!! and therefore I'm confused... I'll try to inspect the class file with the javap tool

Comment: javap returns nothing where are put then?

Comment: any use case of RetentionPolicy.CLASS ?

Answer (score 22):

**Minimal runnable example**

**Language level**:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@interface RetentionSource {}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@interface RetentionClass {}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface RetentionRuntime {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    @RetentionSource
    class B {}
    assert B.class.getAnnotations().length == 0;

    @RetentionClass
    class C {}
    assert C.class.getAnnotations().length == 0;

    @RetentionRuntime
    class D {}
    assert D.class.getAnnotations().length == 1;
}
```

**Bytecode level**: using `javap` we observe that the `Retention.CLASS` annotated class gets a [RuntimeInvisible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.17) class attribute:

```
#14 = Utf8               LRetentionClass;
[...]
RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations:
  0: #14()
```

while `Retention.RUNTIME` annotation gets a [RuntimeVisible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.16) class attribute:

```
#14 = Utf8               LRetentionRuntime;
[...]
RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
  0: #14()
```

and the `Runtime.SOURCE` annotated `.class` does not get any annotation.

[Examples on GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/java-cheat/blob/8e401adf2bfd2eccf653e4daa85a7a21caae1b3d/bytecode/javac-generated/RetentionClass.java) for you to play with.

Comment: So any idea what's the use of Runtime.SOURCE and Runtime.CLASS ?

Comment: @PraveenKamath I don't know any example where they are useful. Likely only happens if you are doing lower level JVM stuff that most devs never do. Let me know if you find an application for them.

Comment: @PraveenKamath `Runtime.SOURCE` is useful for things that are only checked at compile time (e.g. `@Override`).

Answer (score 11):

Retention Policy: A retention policy determines at what point an annotation is discarded. It is s specified using Java's built-in annotations: `@Retention`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49632147/4770877)

```
1.SOURCE: annotation retained only in the source file and is discarded
          during compilation.
2.CLASS: annotation stored in the .class file during compilation,
         not available in the run time.
3.RUNTIME: annotation stored in the .class file and available in the run time.
```

Answer (score 0):

- **CLASS**
  ：Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler but need not be retained by the VM at run time.
- **RUNTIME**
  ：Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler and retained by the VM at run time, so they may be read reflectively.
- **SOURCE**
  ：Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler.

[Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html)