# Java Annotations - looking for an example of RetentionPolicy.CLASS

Tags: java, annotations

according to Java Annotation API:

> - RetentionPolicy.CLASS 
>           Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the
>     compiler but need not be retained by
>     the VM at run time.
> - RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME 
>           Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the
>     compiler and retained by the VM at run
>     time, so they may be read
>     reflectively.

I am looking for a sample of "CLASS" retention policy. when we need to use this policy instead of RUNTIME policy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of all of the large number of libraries I have in my current project. the only examples I can find are in the [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library, for example [`com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/annotations/GwtCompatible.html).

I'm not really sure why they chose this retention policy, though - perhaps for tools support, where the tools read the class files themselves, rather than going through the reflection API. I'm not sure that I really see the point of this distinction, though.

Answer (score 23):

CLASS Annotations are used in obfuscator tools like http://proguard.sourceforge.net .
For example annotation @KeepName disables name mangling when you need to have your class name unchanged to be able to call methods like Class.forName().

Answer (score 8):

RetentionPolicy.CLASS are Useful when doing byte code-level post-processing.

**Example:**

- [Annotations.java from thesmythgroup/DroidCook](https://github.com/thesmythgroup/DroidCook/blob/ba35ca3f36bc0354fba83f34e604ee46af859941/src/org/tsg/android/api/Annotations.java)
- [Retroweaver](https://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 5):

**Minimal example**

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@interface RetentionClass {}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface RetentionRuntime {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    @RetentionClass
    class C {}
    assert C.class.getAnnotations().length == 0;

    @RetentionRuntime
    class D {}
    assert D.class.getAnnotations().length == 1;
}
```

If we use `javap` on the annotated classes, we see that the `Retention.CLASS` annotated class gets a [RuntimeInvisible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.17) class attribute:

```
#14 = Utf8               LRetentionClass;
[...]
RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations:
  0: #14()
```

while `Retention.RUNTIME` annotation gets a [RuntimeVisible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.16) class attribute:

```
#14 = Utf8               LRetentionRuntime;
[...]
RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
  0: #14()
```

So the information is present on both cases in the bytecode.

Therefore, `Runtime.CLASS` can be used to associate arbitrary metadata to a class which bytecode manipulation tools can use, without interfering with runtime-visible behavior.

[Examples on GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/java-cheat/blob/8e401adf2bfd2eccf653e4daa85a7a21caae1b3d/bytecode/javac-generated/RetentionClass.java) for you to play with.

Comment: If I am decompiling a class having annotation `RetentionPolicy.CLASS` (e.g. `@VisibleForTesting` from Guava) then the annotation is not showing up in the decompiled class file. But as per javadoc this type of annotation are recorded in the class file, then why it is not showing up in the decompiled java file. Any thoughts?