# RetentionPolicy CLASS vs. RUNTIME

Tags: java, annotations

What is the practical difference between `RetentionPolicy.CLASS` and `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`?

It looks like both are recorded into the bytecode and both may be accessed at the run-time anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Annotations - looking for an example of RetentionPolicy.CLASS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849593/java-annotations-looking-for-an-example-of-retentionpolicy-class)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107970/annotations-retention-policy

Comment: `CLASS` cannot be accessed at runtime using the Reflection API.

Comment: CLASS annotations can be used by special libraries which operate directly with byte-code. For example, BCEL - Bytecode Engineering Library.

Comment: read more here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59236293/4770877

Answer (score 74, accepted):

> both may be accessed at the run-time anyway.

That's not what the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) says:

RUNTIME: Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler and **retained by the VM at run time, so they may be read reflectively**.

CLASS: Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler but **need not be retained by the VM at run time**.

In practice, I'm not aware of any use-cases for `CLASS`. It would only be useful if you wanted to read the bytecode programmatically, as opposed to via the classloader API, but that's a very specialised case, and I don't know why you wouldn't just use `RUNTIME`.

Ironically, `CLASS` is the default behaviour.

Comment: I read that of course. Sounds like "need not" does not exclude "may" That is why the question.

Comment: @Dima: If the spec says an implementation doesn't have to do a thing, you'd be foolish to assume it *does* do that thing. Assume it doesn't.

Comment: You must be right. What is not clear is the meaning of words "implementation doesn't have to do a thing" for this rather specific case. At least as it is about RetentionPolicy.CLASS case I assume the implementation MUST keep information in the bytecode. Will anything stop me from extracting it from the bytecode using reflection? If yes (will stop) then what is the meaning of "keeping information in the bytecode"?

Comment: @Dima: You can extract it from the bytecode if you read the bytecode directly. If you use the reflection API, it likely won't be there.

Comment: That may be right. Not sure if existence of RetentionPolicy.CLASS makes much sense in this case. Maybe something more was behind it initially ...

Comment: Well, I actually see a use-case for CLASS retention: using AOP tools, with load-time weaving for example with a Java Agent, you may want to do things when loading the class bytecode. But you may also not want to propagate that information to runtime once you've weaved the aspects you need (for any reason, be it security, performance, information overhead...).

Comment: There is another use case for `CLASS`: Annotations that are only used at compile time, like Proguard's `@Keep` annotation used to exclude classes, methods from obfuscation.

Comment: @RobertB wouldn't retention policy `SOURCE` be sufficient in that case?

Comment: it is said that **findbugs** offers some annotations with CLASS retention.

Comment: IDEs use `CLASS` retention annotations all the time...

Answer (score 8):

> It looks like both are recorded into the bytecode and both may be accessed at the run-time anyway.

False for basic built-in annotation interfaces like `getAnnotations`. E.g.:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@interface RetentionClass {}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface RetentionRuntime {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    @RetentionClass
    class C {}
    assert C.class.getAnnotations().length == 0;

    @RetentionRuntime
    class D {}
    assert D.class.getAnnotations().length == 1;
}
```

so the only way to observe a `RetentionPolicy.CLASS` annotation is by using a bytecode parser.

Another difference is that the `Retention.CLASS` annotated class gets a [RuntimeInvisible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.17) class attribute, while `Retention.RUNTIME` annotations get a [RuntimeVisible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.16) class attribute. This can be observed with `javap`.

[Examples on GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/java-cheat/blob/8e401adf2bfd2eccf653e4daa85a7a21caae1b3d/bytecode/javac-generated/RetentionClass.java) for you to play with.

Answer (score 0):

By default, annotations are not accessible through Reflection APIs.
(RetentionPolicy.CLASS is the default retention policy)

You can specify for your custom annotation if it should be available at runtime, for inspection via reflection. You do so by annotating your annotation definition with the @Retention annotation.

### Try this simple example

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Version {
    int test();
}
```

---

```
@Version(test= 1)
public class Engineer{
   //code
}
```

---

```
public class Main {
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Engineer engineer = new Engineer();
    
        Annotation[] annotations = engineer.getClass().getAnnotations();
        System.out.printf("%d annotations found.", annotations.length);
    }
}
```

Try to run the code again by changing the **RetentionPolicy** of the **Version** annotation to **RetentionPolicy.CLASS** and check the difference.