# Maven Annotation API @Parameter.name() method seems to not work

Tags: java, maven, groovy, annotations, gmaven

I'm developing a Maven 3 plugin by using Groovy together with Maven Annotation Support. In a Mojo class, it seems that `name` or `alias` of `@Parameter` aren't reflected during the runtime:

```
@Parameter(required = true, name = "pathAsAName", alias = "pathAsAnAlias")
File pathAsAField
```

The only way to set the field from the Maven XML configuration is by using

```
<configuration>
      <pathAsAField>/tmp</pathAsAField>
</configuration>
```

and not by using `<pathAsAName>` (or `<pathAsAnAlias>` which I'm not sure what it is exactly for) regardless of the fact that plugin.xml contains

```
<parameter>
      <name>pathAsAName</name>
      <alias>pathAsAnAlias</alias>
      <type>java.io.File</type>
      <required>true</required>
      <editable>true</editable>
      <description></description>
</parameter>
```

When I use `<pathAsAName>/tmp</pathAsAName>` I get an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal ... on project ...: Unable to parse configuration of mojo ...:...:...:... for parameter pathAsAName: Cannot find 'pathAsAName' in class ... -> [Help 1]
```

I'm using maven-core:3.3.3 and maven-plugin-annotations:3.4. And execute it with Maven 3.3.3.

Comment: By definition, ``Parameter`` is annotated with ``@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)`` (the default, [sadly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971234/retentionpolicy-class-vs-runtime))

Comment: I see. Does it mean the author (Olivier Lamy in this case) intended to use a class post-processor that would generate "something" "somewhere" (such as `maven-plugin-plugin` with its goal `descriptor`) so that this information can be used for the configuration purposes? But sadly, it is not used at all, if I understand it right?

Comment: ``RetentionPolicy.CLASS`` instructs the compiler to record reflection metadata in the corresponding *.``class`` file, but it cannot be received with the reflection API at runtime. I think it would be interesting to hack on that... :D

Comment: You mean to record annotation metadata, right?

Comment: Well, some of the annotation metadata is used anyway such as "property" and others which makes it even more confusing for me.

Comment: Experimentally, it should be possible to read left information. But I don't recommend to use such code in a productive environment. The class ``Class`` retrieves the annotation metadata with ``native byte[] getRawAnnotations();``