# How can I access a RetentionPolicy.CLASS java annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

Is there a way to configure a ClassLoader or a JVM to load annotations with CLASS retention policy, so I can access them using reflection?

This is useful for compile-time post-processing, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849593/java-annotations-looking-for-an-example-of-retentionpolicy-class).
I annotate some of my classes in order to generate an antlib.xml file automatically.  I would prefer if my annotation could have CLASS retention policy, so that it does not create runtime dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javac can process source and class level annotations, with the `-processor` option.  See javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor.  (Since java 1.6).

I started using it while compiling .java files.  Apparently it can also be used to process CLASS annotations with .class input files.  I haven't tried this because I'm using ant to compile, and ant does not seem to pass .class files to the compiler.

I have to do a full compile when I want to process all the annotations in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to have a look at [this tutorial](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101).

It explains how to create your own annotation processor and how to use it to generate code. It doesn't handle bytecode manipulation though.

He also gave a presentation available on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/43FFfTyDYEg). In case you're too lazy to read... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative technique that can be used during test or application execution (as opposed to during compilation) is to use ASM to load the underlying class file for the annotated class. ASM tree nodes include an "invisibleAnnotations" list for all `RetentionPolicy.CLASS` annotations. The ASM event API has an equivalent.

I have never encountered an open-source library that does this, but have done it for a closed-source project, so it does work.