# Understanding the use of 'Annotations'

Tags: java, annotations, jvm

I'm trying to understand the use of 'Annotations' *a bit better*.
I understand that:

- How to access annotations in my code for [example via this complete tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/).
- I can create methods to perform [desired operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/annotations.html)

To understand this better, I created a virtual problem as following:

> There are *Annotations* `TestAnnotation1`, `TestAnnotation2`, `TestAnnotation3`(definition is available latter in the question). I wants to execute the methods of class `MethodsExecutorClass` as following:
>
> - When `TestClass.java` compiles then execute `CommonMethod()` and `RetentionPolicySOURCEMethod()`
> - When `TestClass.class` loads then execute `CommonMethod()` and `RetentionPolicyCLASSMethod()`
> - Whenever `testMethod()` method of `TestClass.java` executes then execute `CommonMethod()` and `RetentionPolicyRUNTIMEMethod()`

**By this example I wants to understand following**:

- Can I instruct Java compiler (`javac`) or Java Runtime Environment (`jvm`) to execute a method in my class(e.g. CommonMethod()`and`RetentionPolicySOURCEMethod()`methods of`MethodsExecutorClass`).
- Can I delegate the *monitoring* (i.e. searching the methods/classes which are using my annotation etc.) to any other *entity*(which is available in Java SE).
- I want to do something like `@Override` and `@deprecated` annotations. We don't do something extra. Although [on Oracle javadoc site, here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/annotations.html) **it is clearly mentioned** that *The Java platform has always had various ad hoc annotation mechanisms.* and `@deprecated` is one of them. But I wondered If I can do something like this.

*Definitions should look like as following:*

*MyAnnotations.java*:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface TestAnnotation1 
{
  String className();
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface TestAnnotation2 
{
  String className();
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestAnnotation3 
{
  String className();
  String methodName();
}
```

*MethodsExecutorClass.java*:

```
class MethodsExecutorClass
{
    public static void CommonMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("In method: CommonMethod()");
    }

    public void RetentionPolicySOURCEMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("In method: RetentionPolicySOURCEMethod()");
        //Also print annotation arguments e.g. Class name etc
    }

    public void RetentionPolicyCLASSMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("In method: RetentionPolicyCLASSMethod()");
        //Also print annotation arguments e.g. Class name etc
    }

    public void RetentionPolicyRUNTIMEMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("In method: RetentionPolicyRUNTIMEMethod()");
        //Also print annotation arguments e.g. Class name etc
    }
}
```

*TestClass.java*:

```
@TestAnnotation1(TestClass.class)
@TestAnnotation2(TestClass.class)
class TestClass
{
    @TestAnnotation2(TestClass.class, "testMethod()")
    public void testMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("In method: testMethod()");
    }
}
```

May you help me in achieving this? (Please no *guess or assumptions, but presumptions* would be also helpful).
**I'm not sure if this can be achieve, but looking forward.**

Comment: Are you looking for how to use annotations via reflection mechanism in Java?

Comment: @statut No, I got several examples on the Internet about this. I wants to do something like, I'll provide my annotations(`TestAnnotation1`, `TestAnnotation2` etc.) and _classes having method to execute on different scenerios_(e.g. `MethodsExecutorClass`). Now when any developer is compiling/running his code(he may or may not use my annotations) then respective methods should be invoke (e.g. `CommonMethod()`). The developer may need to do some configuration (e.g. we set `CLASS_PATH`) , otherwise he should not be bothered.

Comment: _I can pass the whole source file to my another class (e.g. `HandleCompileTimeAnnotations`) to handle `SOURCE` retention policy, but_ __I don't want to do something like this__.

Comment: There is a concept of "Custom Annotation" in Java. You can build your own, and implement it as per your need.

Comment: @UmeshKumarSharma I have already defined _Custom Annotation_ e.g. `TestAnnotation1 `, `TestAnnotation2` etc. But I have no idea about _how to implement this?_. Because I don't know in advance that which other classes are using my _Custom Annotation_. Moreover, it can be case that _some other user defined his class in future and using the Custom Annotation_.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations with retention policy `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE` are only available during compilation time of the code so your compiler should support your annotation to use it, otherwise it's not possible to handle the annotation. Usually, such annotations are used to detect possible problems at compilation time, for example, annotation `@Override`. That's why your first problem can't be implemented in usual ways.

Annotations with retention policy `RetentionPolicy.CLASS` are available only in `.class` files and can be used via JVMs. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374597/how-can-i-access-a-retentionpolicy-class-java-annotation) how it can be used. The second your problem also can't be implemented via standard ways.

Commonly used annotations are with retention policy `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME` that are available via [reflection mechanism](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html) in Java. But to solve your third problem you have to use some method invocation interceptors, for example, via [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). After that you can get method's annotations via [method.getDeclaredAnnotations()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaredAnnotations()).

> Can I instruct Java compiler (javac) or Java Runtime Environment (jvm)
>   to execute a method in my class(e.g.
>   CommonMethod()andRetentionPolicySOURCEMethod()methods
>   ofMethodsExecutorClass`).

No, you can't.

> Can I delegate the monitoring (i.e. searching the methods/classes
>   which are using my annotation etc.) to any other entity(which is
>   available in Java SE).

You can do it via AOP, for example, use the library [AspectJ](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/).

Comment: I understand _RetentionPolicy_ that's why I'm expecting to call   `RetentionPolicySOURCEMethod()` only at compile time not latter. I wan't to do something like `@Override` and `@deprecated` annotations. We don't do something extra. Although [on Oracle javadoc site, here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/annotations.html) __it is clearly mentioned__ that _The Java platform has always had various ad hoc annotation mechanisms._ and `@deprecated` is one of them. But I wondered If I can do something like this.

Comment: You can do something like this if you implement your own compiler.