# What is a use case for AnnotationRetention.BINARY?

Tags: kotlin

According to the [Kotlin language spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/annotations.html#annotation-retention), there are three types of annotation retention:

> - Source retention (accessible by source-processing tools);
> - Binary retention (retained in compilation artifacts);
> - Runtime retention (accessible at runtime).

Looking at the KDoc for kotlin-stdlib on the JVM we get the following:

```
public enum class AnnotationRetention {
    /** Annotation isn't stored in binary output */
    SOURCE,
    /** Annotation is stored in binary output, but invisible for reflection */
    BINARY,
    /** Annotation is stored in binary output and visible for reflection (default retention) */
    RUNTIME
}
```

I can understand the use cases for `SOURCE` (available for inspection by annotation processors) and `RUNTIME` (available for inspection using reflection) but I cannot understand a use case for `BINARY`.

Can someone please explain a use case for this type of retention? Why would I choose `BINARY` over `SOURCE` if I don't need `RUNTIME`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849593/java-annotations-looking-for-an-example-of-retentionpolicy-class (`RetentionPolicy.CLASS` is the equivalent of `AnnotationRetention.BINARY`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the comment by [Alexey Romanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9204/alexey-romanov), there is a use case for annotations outside annotation processing and runtime reflection which is shown in the answers for [Java Annotations - looking for an example of RetentionPolicy.CLASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849593/java-annotations-looking-for-an-example-of-retentionpolicy-class)

For instance, Proguard takes `.jar` files and performs obfuscation and shrinking on them as per the diagram from the [Proguard website](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/home) below:

[image: Proguard pipeline including input jars, shrinking, then output jars]

The `@Keep` annotation tells Proguard not to remove a target during shrinking. This kind of annotation must be present in the binary since Proguard operates on `.jar` files. Since `@Keep` is not intended to be inspected at runtime using reflection, it would be a suitable use case for `AnnotationRetention.BINARY`.