# working of Java Annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, annotations

I want to know, if I've got it correct or not. I've been reading about annotations and wanted to know how all the magic happened. Here's what I think happens. Please let know if otherwise.

Firstly, let's take some annotation. Say `AssertTrue`. Now, the specs of the annotation is provided in `javax.validation.constraints`. Now, as such, AssertTrue does not really do anything. i.e. if I were to do the following

```
public class MyClass{
 @AssertTrue(message = "MyMessage")
 public myMethod(){
 //something
 }
}
```

Now, this particular piece of code is not going to do anything but save the metadata info that on this method `myMethod` I have some additional info i.e. message and annotation. How I make use of this info is upto me.

This is where the hibernate-validator framework comes into picture.

What it does is, that it provides a bunch of classes and it takes in the object that is supposed to be validated. On that object, it will check if AssertTrue annotation is there. If found, it will invoke the method `isValid` that is provided in the implementation of the `AssertTrueImpl`.

Is this what is happening?

Also, I have a few questions. say I have my own custom annotation and I want to provide a framework that checks something. For the sake of argument, let's say I want to do what the hibernate-validator is doing. Now how does one go about it?

Also, when the JVM encounters some annotation, what happens behind the scene? Does it look for some implementation? What exactly does it look for?

i.e. what will JVM do if it encountered `AssertTrue` in my code. Surely it does not have to do much but store some information, and it does not have to go looking for any implementation too, since whenever I call `validator.validate()` that's when it will look for hibernate-validator implementation.

let me know if I have understood it correctly.

Comment: You've got too much for one question here, but you're broadly correct: Annotations are just read by libraries at compile or runtime (look at the different retention options) that then operate on the classes, generally using reflection. The JVM doesn't actively do anything with annotations; you need some library running to look for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The annotation by itself does nothing, it's just metadata that may be used by a processing tool. In this case, Hibernate validator.

The usual procedure for those tools is to scan on the classpath what classes have metadata that they can use to build or enhance a class (by injecting a proxy, or registering an interceptor, or any other kind of operation). They either do scan the classpath, or an external configuration mechanism (xml, json, annotations on a config class [Spring way]) specifies this for the framework so that it knows where to look for annotated classes.

And so, you too, can benefit from annotations on your project, following the same discovery method. In fact, if you happen to work with CDI, you will probably use them a lot. They're quite useful for bean interception, or for providing metadata on your classes that would otherwise have to be treated with a lot of boilerplate code.

I encourage you to use them profusely.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You understand annotations correctly - they are just metadata on [specific members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458535/which-types-can-be-used-for-java-annotation-members) (fields, methods, classes, ...). Some of them are intended for [compile time only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107970/annotations-retention-policy), some of them are intended for runtime. The latter will be available via [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) (basically forming additional metadata on annotated members). There are numerous possibilities of what you can do with this feature, where declarative validation defined by [JSR-303](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#d0e5631) (and implemented by Hibernate Validator) is just one of them.