# Why Not Always Use RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME?

Tags: java

I understand [the difference of the 3 retention policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107970/how-do-different-retention-policies-affect-my-annotations) `SOURCE`, `CLASS` and `RUNTIME`. But why shouldn't I simply always use the `RUNTIME` retention policy ("just to make sure")? It wouldn't hurt, would it?

All I can imagine is class file size and classloading performance but I feel like in most cases this should be negligible.