# junit 5 custom parametrized tests

Tags: java, junit5, parametrized-testing

I'm using Junit 5 parametrized tests with custom name as follow

```
    @ParameterizedTest(name = PARAMETERIZED_TESTS_NAME_PLACEHOLDER)
```

where `PARAMETERIZED_TESTS_NAME_PLACEHOLDER`  is defined in its own utility class

```
public static final String PARAMETERIZED_TESTS_NAME_PLACEHOLDER = "#{index} [{argumentsWithNames}]";
```

the problem I'm facing is that as I'm using extensively the parametrized tests, my code is cluttered by  these `@ParameterizedTest(name = PARAMETERIZED_TESTS_NAME_PLACEHOLDER)`.

so I created a custom annotation to fix this

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.*;

@ParameterizedTest(name = PARAMETERIZED_TESTS_NAME_PLACEHOLDER)
@Inherited
public @interface CustomParametrizedTest {

}
```

but this annotation is ignored when I use it in the test cases

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@ParamterizedTest` annotation appears to have a retention policy of runtime suggesting it's needed and processed at runtime. Try this config

```
@ParameterizedTest(name = PARAMETERIZED_TESTS_NAME_PLACEHOLDER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface CustomParametrizedTest {

}
```

It seems odd to me that this is not the default retention policy for custom annotations, see more from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107970/how-do-different-retention-policies-affect-my-annotations).

Comment: Thanks Sam, this works correctly, actually I was missing the retention policy