# Check @Override annotation presence on method

Tags: java, reflection, overriding

I have a java.lang.reflect.Method method and I want to check if it is marked with @Override annotation.

Was trying to do that with method.isAnnotationPresent(Override.class) but this approach doesn't applicable for this annotation. Also tried MergedAnnotations.from(method).isPresent() but it also doesn't return true for my method with @Override.

Is it possible to check that?

Comment: `@Override` is a source policy type annotation, so no. For you to check an annotation at run time, it has to be marked as a runtime annotation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107970/how-do-different-retention-policies-affect-my-annotations)

Comment: As said before, you cannot do this through reflection. What you _can_ do is use tools like https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/index.html with its https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/checks/annotation/missingoverride.html#MissingOverride rule.

Comment: If you want to check that a method overrides another method, you can check the method's declared class' super class (and further up the chain) to see if a method with the same name and parameter types exists. If you also want to check for interface method implementations you need to go through each interface as well (recursively).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are going to check `java docs` of annotation you will see that the retention policy is `SOURCE`, not `RUNTIME`, which means the annotation is not present at runtime. Also more details check it [Override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html)

Comment: This answer explains _why_ the answer is 'no, you cannot do that'. Just in case it's not clear: The answer is 'no, you cannot check for the presence of an `@Override` annotation at runtime. You can't even check for it in an annotation processor. Only time you can check it is with an AST (i.e. source, not class file) based code processing/linting tool.